# Reading material for distributed systems from practical aspect

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system

I have been developing a distributed application on top of Akka. As the application is getting mature, I see problems related to distributed systems. Forexample,

- during a rolling update of my cluster, some nodes have old jar files and some nodes have new jar file (because it is updated but other are not). This means that within the code I have to support both old and jar code.
- similarly during a rolling update, I can have old and new config on different nodes at the same time.
- currently, I am using Postgres database at the backend. If the VM which is hosting database is down for update, all the other nodes cannot write any data inside.

I have basic idea on how I can fix the above problems but I would also like to know how others have been solving these problems. So, is there any book which focuses on distributed systems from practical aspect?

Comment: I would recommend https://www.amazon.com/Designing-Data-Intensive-Applications-Reliable-Maintainable/dp/1449373321 - it's one of the best books about distributed systems I read.